# Is there a connection between modern colonialism and secularism?

Tags: philosophy-of-history, philosophy-of-culture, colonialism

An aunt of mine, when she arrived in Britain, once jeered at me, calling me a Christian, mostly because she thought of Britain as being Christian. These were the only categories of thought she had. I, being born here, knew very well, just how deeply secular a country Britain was. And this despite all the churches one sees dotted around cities. As Ruskin put it, Europe chose capitalism over Christianity. I wonder in a similar vein just how Jewish the Jewish state of Israel actually is. Take, for example, the remarks of a Palestinian philosopher, Sari Nusseibeh, published in [Haaretz](https://www.haaretz.com/how-to-avoid-a-hellish-future-1.5252050) in 2014:

> There was a time, in the late 1960s, and after the ’67 war, when even I – a conquered Arab and Palestinian – thought I could sense the vibrant and missionary zeal of an extraordinary nation, set to achieve a rare and sublime human condition that would be a model for all to follow, whether friend or foe.
>
> I remember being overawed by the puritanical ideology of young kibbutzniks, as I sat after dusk with them on the steps of the humble convention/dining hall of the kibbutz (Hazorea) where I stayed, listening to them divulge their thoughts and dreams. I didn’t figure in their dreams, of course. But their dreams figured in my consciousness, as I could see these had more to do with building up a new life for themselves than with destroying the life I had ...
>
> ...I can, of course, see and admire beautiful individuals. Israel boasts so many of them – poets, writers, journalists, scholars, artists – and just ordinary people in ordinary jobs, trying to live their harmless lives. But that special luster of an idealistic nation to be admired has vanished. I can no longer see it anywhere. **It has become replaced, in my mind – sorry to say – by what appears to have become a scientifically skilled colonialist group of self-serving thugs, bent on self-aggrandizement, capitalizing on world-guilt for past pains and horrors suffered, and now hiding behind a religious fiction to justify all the pain and suffering it does to my own people, our heritage and culture**

All very European, all very secular. It makes me recall the last two stanzas from a famous poem by Paul Celan, *Todesfuge* (‘Death Fugue’), his comment on the death-camps of Auschwitz-Birkenau, Belsen, Buchenwald, Dachau, and so on:

> Black milk of daybreak we drink you at night
> We drink you at midday and morning we drink you at evening
> We drink and we drink
> A man lives in the house your goldenes haar Margeurite
> Your aschenes Haar Shulamith he plays with his vipers
> He shouts play death more sweetly Death is a master from Deutschland
> He shouts scrape your strings darker you'll rise then in smoke to the sky
> You'll have a grave then in the clouds there you won't lie too cramped
> Black milk of daybreak we drink you at night
> We drink you at midday Death is a master aus Deutschland
> We drink you at evening and morning we drink and we drink
> This Death is ein Meister aus Deutschland his eye it is blue
> He shoots you with shot made of lead shoots you level and true
> A man lives in the house your goldenes Haar Margarete
> He looses his hounds on us grants us a grave in the air
> He plays with his vipers and daydreams
> Der Tod is ein Meister aus Deutschland
> Dein goldenes Haar Margarete
> Dein aschenes Haar Shulamith

Luce Irigray has written:

> This is so not only because there are plenty of Jews in the world who take their tradition seriously without identifying it with the state of Israel, from which they continually dissociate themselves, but also because, as the non-Zionist Jews themselves teach, the richness of Jewish culture and its distinct presence in the spirit of the West and the modern world in general did not establish itself with the creation of the State of Israel, and in fact is seriously threatened by it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105099/discussion-on-question-by-mozibur-ullah-is-it-possible-that-israel-despite-bei).

Comment: Trying to salvage the question given that it is too old to migrate and there is no direct way to flag a question for deletion (I think). In its defense, I think [colonialism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/colonialism/) is a topic in the purview of philosophy. I also think the question has elements of the philosophy of history.

Answer (score 6):

Speaking from a pure political philosophy perspective, this question centers on the difference between the concept 'nation' and the concept 'state.' Technically, a *nation* is a (loosely) self-governing community of people who share a common ethnocultural identity, while a *state* is defined territory governed by a cohesive political entity. In this sense, the *nation* of Israel ostensibly existed even across the diaspora, and the intent of the Zionist movement was to create a physical territory — a *state* — which could serve as a home for this nation. The difficulty, of course, is that the creation of this state effectively rendered Palestinians as a stateless nation, subject to the same potential for prejudice and abuse that the nation of Israel suffered after the diaspora (which is the same fate shared by Kurds, Uyghurs, Rohingya, and other stateless groups, current and historical).

However, If we're going to ask how 'Jewish' the 'Jewish' state of Israel is, we run into a linguistic difficulty. There are three ways to interpret the word 'Jewish' in this context.

1. Identifying as a person of Jewish ancestry: a claim that is not exactly biological and not exactly cultural, but that combines the two in a loose fashion
2. Identifying as a member of the Jewish faith: subscribing to certain principles, attending certain services, participating in certain rites and rituals.
3. Being a 'proper' Jew: which means adhering to certain values, ideals, and philosophies with are viewed to be quintessentially Jewish.

The last one is particularly problematic, since it can be harshly evaluative. Most people of most faiths are poor practitioners of their faith — e.g., both Islam and Christianity claim to be religions of peace, and yet many practitioners on both sides are combative and warlike — and so insisting that an entire nation or state live up to the highest principles of a faith is unrealistic. In this sense, Israel is in fact a Jewish state, even if the state itself does not live up to some particular idealization of Jewish faith.

In the early days of the formation of Israel, Judaic idealism (for better or worse) was easy: the Jewish people had suffered a tremendous, catastrophic act of genocide, and the drive for a homeland in which Jews could lead their lives and practice their faith in safety was keen.  In the decades since, the priorities have shifted from the need to create such a state to the need to defend and expand it; that is intrinsically less noble and pure than the original intention. But that in no way disqualifies the 'nation' aspect of that state.

Comment: -1: If I was interested in linguistic difficulties I would have signalled this.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: I suspect you are disinterested in any answer that doesn't match your preconceptions. But that's not something I concern myself with.

Comment: In terms of the distinction between nations and states above, see the piece [here](http://archive.is/8HLlp) by a philosopher who critiques the whole premise that there is anything noble or even morally acceptable about the idea that *any* modern state should be defined in terms of a specific ethnocultural (or religious) "nation", since the state's geographic boundaries inevitably include many people who are not part of that nation, so such a definition invariably violates their own right to self-determination (and often ends up being an excuse for 'ethnic cleansing').

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah - When you say "He doesn't say that", are you talking about the author of the piece I linked (Joseph Levine) or Ted Wrigley? If Levine, what did I say that was inaccurate? He says "there is a distinction to be made between a people in the ethnic sense and a people in the civic sense" where civic is defined in non-ethnic terms of being a citizen of a state that holds a geographic territory. He then says 'Any state that “belongs” to one ethnic group within it violates the core democratic principle of equality, and the self-determination rights of the non-members of that group.'

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah - I think you probably meant Levine but I wanted to be sure. If that's correct, do you want to engage in substantive discussion (responding to my question about what aspect of my comment you think misrepresents Levine's views, given the parts I quoted) or just be insulting?

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah - I wouldn't divide the world into "fools" and "non-fools" for the purposes of saying latter deserve only insults and dismissal even if they are willing to engage in discussion, that's a recipe for close-mindedness and never changing one's own views or even learning anything new about why others hold different views. From what I've seen here you seem to be completely dismissive of anyone who substantially disagrees with you on any major issue, even if you don't immediately resort to insulting them like you have with me.